# Why does GCC rearrange memory when not using variable addresses?

Tags: c, gcc

So I've encountered this pretty strange thing in C. Here is my source code:

```
int i;
char mrn = 'L';
char ref;
char tmp;
char k = 'Z';
char test = 'A';
char test2 = 'B';
for(i=0;i<1024;i++){
    tmp = *(&ref+i);
    if(isprint(tmp)){
        printf("%c", tmp);
    }
}
```

It's just simple program that prints printable bytes in memory in higher memory address. **It's expectable to print only 'L'.** But that didn't happen. It printed out "BAZL". ***BUT*** when I accessed these memory addresses before returning like this

```
printf("\n");
printf("test2 @ %p\n", &test2);
printf("test @ %p\n", &test);
printf("k @ %p\n", &k);
printf("tmp @ %p\n", &tmp);
printf("ref @ %p\n", &ref);
printf("mrn @ %p\n", &mrn);
printf("i @ %p\n", &i);
printf("\n");
```

it suddenly acted like it should. Because stack grows upwards towards lower memory addresses, it printed only 'L'. I understand that and why it happened. But why does the compiler rearange the memory when not using the actual addresses ?

Comment: A compiler can arrange the locations/offsets of variables any way it chooses. I'm not even sure you can reasonably expect a completely non-optimized compile to place variables in ascending (or descending) address order.

Comment: Stack-smashing protection. In other words, the compiler's *goal* is to prevent the kind of thing you're trying to do.

Comment: if you want a specific order, you need to allocate a chunk of a heap and fill it in a particular order. Gcc will also keep relative order of the fields inside a struct, but cannot guarantee their alignment, unless you  make it 'packed' via gcc attributes.

Comment: Your complete initialisation is probably done by one 32 bit store. So they are placed together  You can have some control over the placement of the particular variables in the static storage by using linker script and compiler attributes or pragmas

Comment: @Serge it is not gcc. It comes from the standard

Comment: So is there a way to make sure the variables are placed "as expected" ?

Comment: the posted code has no 'main()' function, is missing two critical `#include` statements and does not compile.  How do you expect us to reproduce the problem when you have not included all the needed information?

Comment: It might have optimized out some of the variables, or stored them in registers. But this is less likely to happen if you request address of variable.

Comment: Some of those variables aren't even used by the code. So they'd just be left out as unused.

Comment: If you need variables placed in some expected order, define a struct to 'hold' those variables.  You have complete control over the order in a struct.  You may not have control over padding in a struct (neither do you with individual variables), but nearly all compilers have extensions to give you that control, too.